# Tuning an L-band dish for receiving GOES signals

Tags: antenna, software-defined-radio, satellites, goes, parabolic-dish

I've encountered some challenges with my ground station intended for receiving images from GOES satellites, and I'm seeking your expertise to troubleshoot the issue. Here are the system specifications:

- Dish Size: 1.9m
- GOES Frequency: 1691.4 MHz
- Satellite Elevation: 66
- degrees 22dB Wideband LNA (1.5 to 2.5 GHz) directly connected to the
  feed, powered by a Bias-Tee
- 3m M-M N-type RF cable with a 0.6dB cable from the LNA to an F-F RF adaptor
- 50m M-M thick RF cable from the RF adaptor to the radio, with a 6dB
  loss at the L-band

Despite these specifications, I haven't been able to detect any signals on my SDR receiver. Our initial troubleshooting involved addressing pointing errors, confirmed by referencing the sun. The cables were tested with a yagi, successfully receiving packets from UHF satellites.

One area we're exploring is the focal length. The dish's manufacturer recommends 85.5cm, but our measurements indicate a depth between 28 and 30cm, corresponding to a focal length of 75.21 to 80.58cm. Could this discrepancy be causing the issue?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If the feed is a helix, it's not ideal to mount it the way you have - the metal ring may interfere with the helix, especially with it like the third photo. Can you hold it right at the back, around the thick portion? Also the feed says f/D of 0.45, which makes sense as a helix has a fairly narrow beam. It's difficult to feed such a flat dish with a helix. These two effects will reduce the dish gain, but not make it completely deaf.

Comment: GPS satellites should make a good test source, there are many of them and they have 10s of watts, RHCP. They should easily be visible at 1575 if you point the antenna at them.

Comment: Does your LNA have a bandpass or highpass filter on it? A helix like that will be quite sensitive and omni-directional down to 100 MHz, very different to a horn feed. Without a filter, if you live near a city, the LNA may be completely saturated by FM, TV or cellphone signals (take a look with your SDR).

Comment: Last question - if the dish is 1.9 m diameter... the photos make it look like the feed is 1.0 m away from the dish. The feed phase centre will be 5 or 10 mm in front of its back surface, with the label on it. If the feed is 200 mm long its front will be ~600 mm from the dish surface. Is it mounted roughly in the right place? 5 cm error won't spoil its gain and pattern too much (especially as you're under-illuminating it) but 2x F will be pretty bad.

Comment: Thanks @tomnexus We currently don't use any filter. We plan to install one soon and retest the system. We have verified that the distance between the feed front and the base of the dish is 85.5cm, corresponding to 0.45 F/D. I tried to track GPS satellites at 1575MHz but couldnt see anything.

Comment: Focal length is measured to the groundplane of the helix, which is probably the surface closest to the connector. (Unless you can see it inside or have other information). Re Filters - try scanning your receiver around 88-108 MHz, see what is there. If you see large signals, the LNA is probably overloaded.

Comment: Please remember that comments are for discussing improvements to the question, and that additional information should be incorporated by editing the question.